# PythonVirtualenvOperator gives error: No module named unusual_prefix_***_dag

Tags: python, kubernetes, airflow, pickle, dill

I'm using airflow 2.5.3 with Kubernetes executor and Python 3.7.

I've tried to make a simple DAG with only one `PythonVirtualnvOperator` and two context variables (`{{ ts }}` and `{{ dag }}`) passed into it.

```
from datetime import timedelta
from pathlib import Path
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator, PythonVirtualenvOperator
import pendulum
 
 
dag = DAG(
    default_args={
        'retries': 2,
        'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=10),
    },
    dag_id='fs_rb_cashflow_test5',
    schedule_interval='0 5 * * 1',
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2020, 1, 1, tz='UTC'),
    catchup=False,
    tags=['Feature Store', 'RB', 'u_m1ahn'],
    render_template_as_native_obj=True,
)
 
context = {"ts": "{{ ts }}", "dag": "{{ dag }}"}
op_args = [context, Path(__file__).parent.absolute()]
 
 
def make_foo(*args, **kwargs):
    print("---> making foo!")
    print("make foo(...): args")
    print(args)
    print("make foo(...): kwargs")
    print(kwargs)
 
 
make_foo_task = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
        task_id='make_foo',
        python_callable=make_foo,
        provide_context=True,
        use_dill=True,
        system_site_packages=False,
        op_args=op_args,
        op_kwargs={
          "execution_date_str": '{{ execution_date }}',
        },
        requirements=["dill", "pytz", f"apache-airflow=={airflow.__version__}", "psycopg2-binary >= 2.9, < 3"],
        dag=dag)
```

Alas, when I'm trying to trigger this DAG, airflow gives me the following error:

```
[2023-10-23, 13:30:40] {process_utils.py:187} INFO - Traceback (most recent call last):
[2023-10-23, 13:30:40] {process_utils.py:187} INFO -   File "/tmp/venv5ifve2a5/script.py", line 17, in <module>
[2023-10-23, 13:30:40] {process_utils.py:187} INFO -     arg_dict = dill.load(file)
[2023-10-23, 13:30:40] {process_utils.py:187} INFO -   File "/tmp/venv5ifve2a5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 287, in load
[2023-10-23, 13:30:40] {process_utils.py:187} INFO -     return Unpickler(file, ignore=ignore, **kwds).load()
[2023-10-23, 13:30:40] {process_utils.py:187} INFO -   File "/tmp/venv5ifve2a5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 442, in load
[2023-10-23, 13:30:40] {process_utils.py:187} INFO -     obj = StockUnpickler.load(self)
[2023-10-23, 13:30:40] {process_utils.py:187} INFO -   File "/tmp/venv5ifve2a5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 432, in find_class
[2023-10-23, 13:30:40] {process_utils.py:187} INFO -     return StockUnpickler.find_class(self, module, name)
[2023-10-23, 13:30:40] {process_utils.py:187} INFO - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'unusual_prefix_4c3a45107010a4223aa054ffc5f7bffc78cce4e7_dag'
```

Why does it give me this strange error -- and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Looks like something the template engine could produce. Have you tried providing the DAG directly via op_args instead?

Comment: Do you mean -- to pass `op_args=[dag]`?

Comment: Yes, something like that. dag is static, it's not the DagRun, right?

Comment: That `unusual_prefix_` is actually your DAG file being treated as a module. It has to do with how the DagBag is populated by loading the DAG files as if they were Python modules (see [Airflow's code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2.5.3/airflow/models/dagbag.py#L324)) and how when it's trying to be "upickled" by dill, it's not found. What are you trying to do with the DAG object in the Python operator? Knowing this might help provide a workaround. Also: notice that if you don't pass the DAG instance in the context, the task runs fine (IE if you just did `context = {"ts": "{{ ts }}"}`)

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs if this function `make_foo` that is passed to an airflow operator as `python_callable` argument is defined in the same Python source with the DAG object.

And the DAG has finally started working when I moved the `make_foo` function to another Python module.

Here's my code now:

- `dags/strange_pickling_error/dag.py`:

```
import datetime
import pendulum
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator, PythonVirtualenvOperator
import dill

from strange_pickling_error.some_moar_code import make_foo


dag = DAG(
    dag_id='strange_pickling_error_dag',
    schedule_interval='0 5 * * 1',
    start_date=datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1),
    catchup=False,
    render_template_as_native_obj=True,
)


context = {"ts": "{{ ts }}", "dag_run": "{{ dag_run }}"}


make_foo_task = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
    task_id='make_foo',
    python_callable=make_foo,
    use_dill=True,
    system_site_packages=False,
    op_args=[context],
    requirements=[f"dill=={dill.__version__}", f"apache-airflow=={airflow.__version__}", "psycopg2-binary >= 2.9, < 3",
                  f"pendulum=={pendulum.__version__}", "lazy-object-proxy"],
    dag=dag)
```

- `dags/strange_pickling_error/some_moar_code.py`:

```
def make_foo(*args, **kwargs):
    print("---> making foo!")
    print("make foo(...): args")
    print(args)
    print("make foo(...): kwargs")
    print(kwargs)
```